# Bar Code Scanner , Auto focus to next text box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am very new to .Net development. I have requirement to use simple Bar code Scanner which reads the text and displays on text box.

My question is i have 10 boxes in my web page and user wants to scan values in to these 10 box and click on submit. I want to get focus to next  box automatically once he scans in first text box and so.

Focus should move like ( 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 .....)

I have created tab index but the focus is not going to next text box.

Please help

Comment: Could you please show us your code

Comment: How does the barcode scanner signal that it is done reading? Is it a fixed number of characters? Do you get a <RETURN> character? If not, this problem is difficult to solve, because your web page would not know *when* to move the focus.

Comment: It is not having any fixed number of characters. it is returning Enter event after the scanning. Text changed event is working as expected after scanning but auto focus to next text box is not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a function being called when you scan a barcode?

If there is and if you have not modified the names of the textboxes AND if they are in order in your form (i.e., first textbox in the form is textBox1. Second textbox is textBox2 and so on..), you could
1. Do a substring and get the numeric value of that textbox
2. Create a new string variable called `TextBoxName = textbox" + (the numeric value + 1)`
3. Change focus to textbox with the `TextBoxName` as its ID.
4. Put this in the end of your barcode function.

Answer (score 0):

The "Tab Index" will only come into play when the user presses the "tab" button. The cursor will never automatically jump between input boxes without you writing JS to make it do so.

Here's a way to set focus using JQuery in case that helps:

```
$('#myTextBox').focus();
```

Comment: i tried it but didnt work , can you let me know where to use this fucntion,, below is my code.

Comment: <div class="container" style="background-color: #fbfbfb">
   <br />
   <div class="row col-xs-4">
    <div class="col-xs-8 input-group">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtSN1" CssClass="form-control input-sm" TabIndex="2" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" runat="server" placeholder="Serial Number 1"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="col-xs-8 input-group">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtSN2" CssClass="form-control input-sm" TabIndex="3" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" runat="server" placeholder="Serial Number 2"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <br />